# How to get visio shapes vertices

Tags: c#

i am using in my c# project visio activex to import visio floorplan drawings. and i need to get the vertices of the shapes in that drawing, and i can't find any method or property for it. if someone has any ideas please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thank you, your code led me to discover the way.
if you want the vertices of a shape s:
s.pathes[1].point(double tolarence, out array a);
the resuly would be on the one dimensional array a .

Answer (score 0):

[This is something](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mgold/VisioInDotNet12032006222024PM/VisioInDotNet.aspx) that might be helpful to you.

Here are some code snippet to get you started:

```
public void DrawSampleShapeConnection()
{
// get the current draw page
Visio.Page currentPage = axDrawingControl1.Document.Pages[1];

// Load the stencil we want
Visio.Document currentStencil = axDrawingControl1.Document.Application.Documents.OpenEx("Basic_U.vss", (short)Visio.VisOpenSaveArgs.visOpenDocked);

// show the stencil window
Visio.Window stencilWindow = currentPage.Document.OpenStencilWindow();

// this gives a count of all the stencils on the status bar
int countStencils = currentStencil.Masters.Count;

toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = string.Format("Number of Stencils in {0} = {1}", currentStencil.Title, countStencils);
statusStrip1.Refresh();

// create a triangle shape from the stencil master collection
Visio.Shape shape1 = currentPage.Drop(currentStencil.Masters["Triangle"], 1.50, 1.50);

// create a square shape from the stencil master collection
Visio.Shape shape2 = currentPage.Drop(currentStencil.Masters["Square"], 10, 7.50);

// create a dynamic connector from the stencil master collection
Visio.Shape connector = currentPage.Drop(currentStencil.Masters["Dynamic connector"], 4.50, 4.50);

// currentPage.Layout();

// connect the shapes together through the dynamic connector
ConnectShapes(shape1, shape2, connector);

}
```